# armature deform with automatic weights mesh deform

Tags: rigging, armature

I am new to blender. I was following a tutorial. When I applied "armature deform with automatic weights", the left hand of the cartoon works fine while moving the armature. But the right hand gets messed up.

I have added inversekinetics constraint to move the hand. The armature name is *ik.hand.l* for left hand. and *ik.hand.r.001* for right hand.

[image: see the attached image]

The attached blender file is given for reference.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ubYjsbgMNf39_UVACdkFKYhfEJmcph1R/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply the Mirror modifier, then Apply the Subsurface modifier but only 1 level. You can see from the picture that it's plenty smooth enough. Then in object mode [image: weighted]select the mesh, shift select the bones and Ctrl P>Automatic Weights